# How do i Compare Text with double space inside ("a b" isEqual to "a b")?

Tags: javascript

I have some constant text, and I want to check if the user's input is equal to this text with some flexibility.
I want to allow the input to pass even if different by uppercase/lowercase (already know how to do it) or different because of multiple spaces.

```
const statement = 'Please enter this text';

const isEqual = (first, second) => { ... }

isEqual(statement, "please enter this text"); // should be true
isEqual(statement, " please Enter this text "); // should be true
isEqual(statement, "please Enter   this text"); // should be true
isEqual(statement, "please Enterthis text"); // should be false
isEqual(statement, "ple ase Enter this text"); // should be false
```

Comment: So the strings should be equal regardless of spaces in between and case?

Comment: Trim leading and trailing spaces and replace consecutive spaces with  a single one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to :

1. `trim` the string
2. Remove consecutive spaces and replace it with single space and
3. Make it lower case to ignore case sensivity.

```js
const statement = 'Please enter this text';

const normalizeString = (str) => str.trim().replace(/\s+/g," ").toLowerCase()
const isEqual = (first, second) => normalizeString(first) == normalizeString(second)

console.log(isEqual(statement, "please enter this text"))// should be true
console.log(isEqual(statement, " please Enter this text "))// should be true
console.log(isEqual(statement, "please Enter   this text"))// should be true
console.log(isEqual(statement, "please Enterthis text"))// should be false
console.log(isEqual(statement, "ple ase Enter this text"))// should be false
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this function and you will be good to go.

```
const isEqual = (first, second) => {
  return first.toLowercase() === second.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' ).trim().toLowercase();
}
```

Here we replacing multiple spaces with single and then lower-casing both strings, and then comparing them. The lower-casing is importing here.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you just want to know if words are the sames (in the same order) and you don't care how many they have spaces between

```js
const statement = 'Please enter this text';


const isEqual = (first, second) => !first.localeCompare(second.match(/\w+/g).join(' '), 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' })


console.log(isEqual(statement, "please enter this text"   ), 'should be true')
console.log(isEqual(statement, " please Enter this text " ), 'should be true')
console.log(isEqual(statement, "please Enter   this text" ), 'should be true')
console.log(isEqual(statement, "please Enterthis text"    ), 'should be false')
console.log(isEqual(statement, "ple ase Enter this text"  ), 'should be false')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the expected result:

```
    const isEqual = (first, second) => { 
        first = first.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
        second = second.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
        
        if(first == second) {
            return true;
        }
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mine, but [Subesh Bhandari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62608894/7207817) answer's is better

```js
const statement = 'Please enter this text'

const isEqual = (first, second) => {
  const arrFirst = first.toLowerCase().split(' ')
  const arrSecond = second.toLowerCase().split(' ').filter((t) => {
    return t
  })
  console.log(arrFirst.join(' ') === arrSecond.join(' '))
}

console.log(isEqual(statement, "please enter this text")) // should be true
console.log(isEqual(statement, " please Enter this text ")) // should be true
console.log(isEqual(statement, "please Enter   this text")) // should be true
console.log(isEqual(statement, "please Enterthis text")) // should be false
console.log(isEqual(statement, "ple ase Enter this text")) // should be false
```